# Setting timeouts to parse webpages using python lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am using python lxml library to parse html pages:

```
import lxml.html

# this might run indefinitely
page = lxml.html.parse('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Is there any way to set timeout for parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be using `urllib.urlopen` as the opener, but the easiest way to do this would just to modify the default timeout for the socket handler.

```
import socket
timeout = 10
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
```

Of course this is a quick-and-dirty solution.

Comment: This would only stop if the web request to download the page takes too long, not if the _parsing_ takes too long. Did anyone find a way to do that?